# Laravel, attach a pivot table value to Auth::user, what's missing/wrong?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to have **Auth::user()->building** to return the building ID it is attached to. Right now it's returning Null. What am I doing wrong? Should I explicitly declare something somewhere? Thank you.

My tables :

**users** (id, name, etc.)

**buildings**  (id, name)

**building_user** (building_id, user_id) has values ( 7 = building_id, 1 = user_id) with primary key on the two of them combined.

App\User

```
    ...
    public function building(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Building');
    }
    ...
```

and

App\Building

```
  ...
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
  }
  ...
```

** EDIT **

I tried doing $building->users on view, and received the error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.building_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`building_id` = 7 and `users`.`building_id` is not null)
```

Seems it's trying to not do a relational search. And searching the user table for a building_id column.

Comment: Did you set values to $fillable in both User and Building ?

Comment: @NaveenNiraula I have set it only for User.php -  protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'email', 'password'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need a third table (`building_user`) unless you have something else in mind.

You need to make some modifications in your `users` table.

- Add a field named `building_id` for storing the corresponding building_id the user belongs to.
- Make a relation from `building_id` to reference `id` on `buildings` table.

Of course remove the third table, you don't need it if you've done the above steps.

Then `Auth::user()->building()->id` gives you the building id of the logged in user.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse